# Designing a model for easier interaction between objects

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

In my .NET application, the data model is contained in a few classes:
Call, Phone, Connection

For each type, i have a "**managing**" entity (CallManager, PhoneManager, etc).

Each type implements an interface, in order to be able to switch implementations later on, or to mock out some classes for testing purposes:

```
public class CallManager : ICallManager
public class PhoneManager : IPhoneManager
```

Finally, a "master" object has a reference to each of these managers, and uses them to retrieve/update the needed object instance (for example, creating a new Call object and storing it in CallManager, retrieving a phone object from PhoneManager, etc).

Such an object takes on a dependency on each of these types:

```
public class AppManager
{
    public AppManager(ICallManager callManager, IPhoneManager phoneManager, etc...)
}
```

Is there any design principle or pattern that facilitates interactions between various objects to ease on the task of maintaining the data correctly and updating it, without having a dense set of inter-relations between all of these manager objects, and without having one class that is dependant on all other classes?

Comment: One way or the other, the AppManager class would be dependent on functionality from 4 different objects, which in turn are inter-related as well.

Comment: +1 Great question. Excellent use of Interfaces, I might add.

Comment: Perhaps some more code to show what you are trying to avoid?  Your AppManager class, as the container for your application, is required to store those susbsytem references, and that is fine as long as you do it via Interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially it sounds like you are using the Mediator pattern. But the Mediator is still going to need to access the object instances.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

It sounds like you have also already implemented the Factory pattern, but reading up on it may lead to some inspiration.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

Answer (score 2):

Another option you could think of using is the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This helps to reduce the hard interconnections between objects. You update an object and this results in an event and a set of objects unknown to the original modified objects are notified of this event. Here there is no complicated criss-cross communication. Only a wiring of the objects needed just after the creation of these objects. You could also refer [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/object-wiring-an-observer-observable-pattern/1046175).